# MySQL - fill-level RANGE - how to get it?

Tags: mysql, range

I am looking at a case in which we have a number of tanks filled with liquid. The amount of liquid is measured and information is stored in a database. This update is done every 5 minutes. Here the following information is stored:

- tankId
- FillLevel
- TimeStamp

I would like to read out the database and categorize each tank in one of the following 'fill-level' ranges:

- Range A: 0 - 40%
- Range B: 40 - 75%
- Range C: 75 - 100%

In the end I would like to have the amount of tanks which are in RANGE A, which are in B and which are in range C. I can select fill-level of a `DISTINCT TankId` but that does not work ...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tankId) 
FROM TankDemo 
WHERE (filllevel > 0 AND filllevel < 40);
```

Obviously it does not provide me the correct count of tanks per range. Hope some of you have suggestions how I can get this data.

Thanks a lot

Comment: See CASE. Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>=0 and filllevel<40 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range A',
        sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>=40 and filllevel<=79 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range B',
        sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>79 and filllevel<=100 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range C'
FROM TankDemo ;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried this and it separates the fill_level great per RANGE. The challenge now it to get ONLY the latest data per tank (will post an example of data below)

Comment: Don't do it, just make another question. If this one it's solved, accept the answer and upvote it, please

Answer (score 0):

By using case statement you can achieve the result that you want. Try below one it will work as you like

```
SELECT count(distinct
            CASE
                WHEN filllevel>=0 and filllevel<40 
                THEN tankId END) AS 'Range A',
            count(distinct
            CASE
                WHEN filllevel>=40 and filllevel<=75
                THEN tankId END) AS 'Range B',
           count(distinct
            CASE
                WHEN filllevel>75and filllevel<=100 
                THEN tankId
            END) AS 'Range C'
    FROM TankDemo ;
```